# how to handle db schema updates when using schemabinding and updating often

Tags: sql-server, code-generation, version-control

I'm using a MS SQL Server db and use plenty of views (for use with an O/R mapper). A little annoyance is that I'd like to

- use schema binding
- update with scripts (to deploy on servers and put in a source control system)

but run into the issue that whenever I want to e.g. add a column to a table, I have to first drop all views that reference that table, update the table, and then recreate the views, even if the views wouldn't need to be updated otherwise. This makes my update scripts a lot longer and also, looking the diffs in the source control system, it is harder to see what the actual relevant change was.

Is there a better way to handle this?

I need to still be able to use simple and source-controllable sql updates. A code generator like is included in SQL Server Management Studio would be helpful, but I had issues with SQL Server Management Studio in that it tends to create code that does not specify the names for some indices or (default) constraints. But I want to have identical dbs when I run my scripts on different systems, including the names of all contraints etc, so that I don't have to jump through loops when updating those constraints later.

So perhaps a smarter SQL code generator would a solution?

My workflow now is:

- type the `alter table` statement in query editor
- check if I get an error statement like "`cannot ALTER 'XXX' because it is being referenced by object 'YYY'`."
- use SQL Server Managment Studio to script me `create` code for the referenced object
- insert a `drop` statement before the alter statement and create statement after
- check if the `drop` statement creates error and repeat

this annoys me, but perhaps I simply have to live with it if I want to continue using schemabinding and script updates...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can at least eliminate the "check if I get an error" step by querying a few dynamic managment functions and system views to find your dependencies. [This article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1768) gives a decent explanation of how to do that. Beyond that, I think you're right, you can't have your cake and eat it too with schema-binding.

Also keep in mind that dropping/creating views will cause you to lose any permissions that were granted on those objects, so those permissions should be included in your scripts as well.

Comment: Oh, well. I guess I'll live with it. Ideally what I would like is: a) no error message if the table update doesn't really affect views (e.g. adding a new column shouldn't affect read only views on this table)
b) error message if the table updates breaks views (eg dropping a column that is used in a view)
But I guess MSSQL just doesn't work that way (possibly for good reasons...)
Thanks for the permissions reminder!